# How to position subfloat captions (subfig) individially per subfloat?

Tags: positioning, subfig, horizontal

I'm trying to put several subfloats (tikzpicture) into one large figure. As you can see in the attatched image, the subfig captions ((a)...(f)) look weird. I am using:

```
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[position=bottom]{subfig}
```

and my subfigs are set up like this:

```
\begin{figure*}
    \subfloat[ ]{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            ...
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \hfill
    \subfloat[ ]{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            ...
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    ...
\end{figure*}
```

They are centered horizontally, however, since my tikzpictures are set up weird it looks wonky.
I want to place each subcaption underneath the middle of each plot (e.g. under "F-Arrow"). Is there a setting for the subfig package that lets me define a different horizontal shift per subcaption? I have no problem with tweaking values manually for this problem :)

Sophie

[image: Screenshot of my current result.]

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [here](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=28543). The solution is to use

```
\captionsetup[subfigure]{oneside,margin={1.4cm,0cm}}
```

before each subfloat. In my example:

```
\begin{figure*}
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{oneside,margin={2.0cm,0cm}}
    \subfloat[ ]{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            ...
     \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \hfill
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{oneside,margin={1.3cm,0cm}}
    \subfloat[ ]{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            ...
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    ...
\end{figure*}
```

[image]